# Quadratic reciprocity law property of primes of the form $4k+1$ depending from $2$ being a square modulo $p$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, square-numbers, quadratic-reciprocity

Let us consider the following two properties (cases) of a prime $p$ that has the form $4k+1$ and a natural (not necessarily square-free) number $n<p$:

- ***$2$ is a square modulo $p$:*** If $n$ is a square modulo $p$, and none of the prime factors of $n$ is of the form $4k+1$, and no pair of prime factors of $n$ (not necessarily distinct) are both of the form $4k−1$, then $p$ is a square modulo $n$
- ***$2$ is not a square modulo $p$:*** If $n$ is a square modulo $p$, $n$ is odd, and none of the prime factors of $n$ is of the form $4k+1$,  and no pair of prime factors of $n$ (not necessarily distinct) are both of the form $4k−1$, then $p$ is a square modulo $n$.

Althought I searched for indicators (including proofs) that these properties are well-known, however, I could not find concrete/established material.

***My question:***
Are these properties known or embodied in existing theorems? I would be greatful for any hints or directions to investigate.

In the case that there are no references to this yet, how we can approach a proof (I am not asking for a complete proof here at all - I would be very grateful for an impulse into the right direction).

Comment: Is the statement “none of the prime factors of $n$…” meant as a condition, or a conclusion? Because it reads as a conclusion, which is false. If it is meant as a condition, write “ **and** none of the prime factors…”

Comment: Correct -  "none of the prime factors of $n$…" is a condition. The conclusion refers only to the (small) ", then ..." part. Thanks for your hint. Just fixed it by writing as suggested **and**...

Comment: If I’m reading it correctly, the first case requires $n=2^m$ or $n=2^mq,$ with $q$ prime of the form $4k-1.$ It is certainly true, since $(2/p)=1$ iff $p\equiv \pm 1\pmod8.$ Since $p-1$ is divisible by $4,$ this means that $p\equiv1\pmod8.$ So $p$ is a square modulo any $2^m.$ For $n=2^mq,$ then $q$ is a square modulo $p.$ Since $p\equiv1\pmod 4,$ reciprocity means $p$ is a square modulo $q,$ and hence, a square modulo $n.$ But this doesn’t require $q\equiv -1\pmod 4.$ It is true for all odd primes $q,$ I believe.

Comment: The second case requires $n=1$ or $n$ a prime of the form $4k-1.$

Comment: Thank you very much for your hint. One idea to the second case: Let us not restrict $n$ to prime values (and not consider the propositions as  "if and only if"). There is quadratic reciprocity between $997$ and $3\cdot19$. It would be great if this generalization works.